# Enlarge image view on iOS

Tags: ios, facebook, image, image-enlarge

I am trying to find a way to open an image in fullscreen from a thumbnail, in the same style the Facebook app on iOS does. https://i.stack.imgur.com/zjvrg.png Here is what I have and would like to enlarge the picture of the tram.

Any help would be great
Thanks
Matt McInnes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9934031/how-to-enlarge-uiimageview-when-tapped) Might Help You  [How To Enlarge UIImageView When Tapped](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9934031/how-to-enlarge-uiimageview-when-tapped)

```
- (IBAction)buttonTapped:(id)sender {

[self.imageView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 80)];

}
```